# Thumbnail image is not transferred into another folder

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, file-upload

I create a **form** which contain one **image-array(name="image[]",type="file")** to **upload multiple images**.And when user click on save button **image** is **save** in **destination folder** and **with** that **thumbnail is create** and it is **save** at **its destination** folder.

On **local side** everything is **alright** but when I upload it **on server image is save in its destination** but the **thumbnails is not transfer to its destination folder**.also **folder** for thumbnail is **not create on server side**.where on **local-side** folder is also **create** for thumbnails.

```
/* code for making thumbnails and upload it */

$fileName = $file[$fieldname]['name'][$i];

// $fileName    = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9._]/", "",$fileName);

$fileTemp   = $file[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$i];
$dest = JPATH_ROOT . "\\"."images"."\\"."machines"."\\"."machines"."\\".$fileName;

$dest2 = JPATH_ROOT . "\\"."images"."\\"."machines"."\\"."thumbnails"."\\".$fileName;

$dest3 = JPATH_ROOT . "\\"."images"."\\"."machines"."\\"."thumbnails";

$dest3=str_replace("/","\\",$dest3);

$dest=str_replace("\\administrator/components/com_machine",null,$dest); //for image upload

$dest2=str_replace("\\administrator/components/com_machine",null,$dest2); // for  thumbnail creation
$dest=str_replace("/","\\",$dest);
$dest2=str_replace("/","\\",$dest2);

$filePath   =$dest;
$filePath2  =$dest2;

//Check for allowed extensions
$uploadedFileNameParts  = explode('.',$fileName);
$uploadedFileExtension  = array_pop($uploadedFileNameParts);
$uploadedFileExtension  = strtolower($uploadedFileExtension);
$validFileExts          = explode(',', 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif');

    //assume the extension is false until we know its ok
    $extOk = false;

    //go through every ok extension, if the ok extension matches the file extension (case insensitive)
    //then the file extension is ok
    foreach($validFileExts as $key => $value){
        if(preg_match("/$value/i", $uploadedFileExtension )){
            $extOk          = true;
            $fileExtension  = $value;
        }
    }


    // Check if acceptable extension
    if($extOk == false){
         $info['error'] = 1;
         $info['msg']   = JText::_('Not acceptable image extension');

        return $info;
    }



    if($fileName){
        // Try to upload file
        if(JFile::upload($fileTemp, $filePath)){
        //  JFile::upload($newimage, $dest2);


         //------------------thumbnail creation----------------
            $n_width=100; 
            $n_height=100; 



                     if(!is_dir($dest3))
                    {
                           mkdir($dest3);
                           chmod($dest3,0666);
                    } 

            //image creation
            if($file[$fieldname]['type'][$i]=="image/gif")
                { 
                $im=imagecreatefromgif("{$dest}");
                $width=imagesx($im); // Original picture width is stored
                $height=imagesy($im); // Original picture height is stored
                $n_height=($n_width/$width) * $height; // Add this line to maintain aspect ratio
                $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($n_width,$n_height);
                imagecopyresized($newimage,$im,0,0,0,0,$n_width,$n_height,$width,$height);
                if (function_exists("imagegif")) {
                header("Content-type: image/gif");
                imagegif($newimage,"{$dest2}");
                chmod($dest2,0666);
                //move_uploaded_file($newimage,$dest2);

                }

                elseif (function_exists("imagejpeg")) {
                    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
                    imagejpeg($newimage,"{$dest2}");

                    chmod($dest2,0666);
                    }
                    }////////// end of gif file thumb nail creation//////////

            ////////////// starting of JPG thumb nail creation//////////
            //echo $dest2;
                    if($file[$fieldname]['type'][$i]=="image/jpeg"){
                    $im=imagecreatefromjpeg("{$dest}"); 
                    $width=imagesx($im); // Original picture width is stored
                    $height=imagesy($im); // Original picture height is stored
                    $n_height=($n_width/$width) * $height; // Add this line to maintain aspect ratio
                    $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($n_width,$n_height); 
                    imagecopyresized($newimage,$im,0,0,0,0,$n_width,$n_height,$width,$height);

                    imagejpeg($newimage,"{$dest2}");
                    chmod($dest2,0666);
                //  move_uploaded_file($newimage,$dest2);
                    }

                    if($file[$fieldname]['type'][$i]=="image/png"){
                    $im=imagecreatefrompng("{$dest}"); 
                    $width=imagesx($im); // Original picture width is stored
                    $height=imagesy($im); // Original picture height is stored
                    $n_height=($n_width/$width) * $height; // Add this line to maintain aspect ratio
                    $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($n_width,$n_height); 
                    imagecopyresized($newimage,$im,0,0,0,0,$n_width,$n_height,$width,$height);

                    imagepng($newimage,"{$dest2}");
                    chmod($dest2,0666);
                //  move_uploaded_file($newimage,$dest2);
                    }
                //  move_uploaded_file($newimage,"$dest2");

                //  exit;    
            //------------------end thumbnail creation--------------


            //JFile::upload($newimage, $dest3);


            $info['error']  = 0;
            $info['msg']    = JText::_('record saved');

            return $info;
        } 
    } else {
        $info['error']  = 1;
        $info['msg']    = JText::_('No image selected to upload');

        return $info;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code your using for the upload as I bet the paths have not been defined correctly

Answer (score 1):

I can see why it may not work on a different hosting environment. Your paths are being destroyed with `str_replace` etc. Keep things simple like so:

```
$dest  = JPATH_ROOT . '/images/machines/machines/' . $fileName;
$dest2 = JPATH_ROOT . '/images/machines/thumbnails/' . $fileName;    
$dest3 = JPATH_ROOT . '/images/machines/thumbnails";

JFile::upload($fileTemp, $dest);
JFile::upload($newimage, $dest2);
```

Comment: When I write this JFile::upload($newimage, $dest2); there is error will generate like: "failed to move file"

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code using `var_dump();` with the variable? Have you ensured your `tmp` path in the global configuration is correct?

Comment: var_dump(); returns false.What does it mean.I write var_dump($newimage); after $newimage;

Comment: `var_dump` dumps the data for the variable. As mentioned before, ensure you have set up your `tmp` paths correctly in the configuration.php and start using `var_dump($foo)` from the top of your script to ensure that all variables return the desired value

Comment: ok.i will try..

Comment: its done.@Lodder..The mistake is this.  "$im=imagecreatefromgif **($dest)**;"  here I give the reference of **$dest** which is path of uploaded file in server which is not accessible on FTP Server.so first i have to assign the path of image and after that it will upload..btw thnkssss